# Generating random numbers: CPU vs GPU, which currently wins?

Tags: c++, optimization, random, cuda, hardware

I've been working on a physics simulations requiring the generation of a large amount of random numbers (at least 10^13 if you want an idea). I've been using the C++11 implementation of the Mersenne twister. I've also read that GPU implementation of this same algorithm are now a part of Cuda libraries and that GPU can be extremely efficient at this task; but I couldn't find explicit numbers or a benchmark comparison. For example compared to an 8 cores i7, are Nvidia cards of the last generations more performant in generating random numbers? If yes, how much and in which price range?

I'm thinking that my simulation could gain from having a GPU generating a huge pile of random numbers and the CPU doing the rest.

Comment: try it and see? there are so many gpus and cpus around that will vary in their speeds...

Comment: It probably depends on the algorithm...

Comment: @PlasmaHH : Unfornutanely I don't have any Nvidia card at disposition and I can't, unfortunately again, spend money without knowing what to expect

Comment: @Mine: I'm only looking for comparision data between both Mersenne twister random number generation, the one inside the <random> library on the CPU side and the implementation already part of the Cuda library on the GPU side.

Comment: One key aspect is what will you do with the random numbers? If you need them in the CPU memory, no matter how fast the generation on the GPU is, the transfer time might render the approach uneffective.

Comment: Why do you claim that there are no numbers around? Take a look at [Parallel Random Number Generation Using OpenMP, OpenCL and PGI Accelerator Directives](http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v2n2a4.htm) and [Mersenne Twister Random Number Generation on FPGA, CPU and GPU](http://www.see.ed.ac.uk/~slig/papers/tian_AHS09.pdf)? Although somewhat dated, perhaps you can get a feeling.

Comment: no matter which is faster, combine the two and it'll be fastest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some comparisons can be found here:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuRAND

Comment: Right, definitely what I was looking, sadly they don't compare it to the default c++11 random number generator. Still, I'm pretty sure that I had already found a page giving the # of random number generated / s for different CPUs, if I manage to find it back I may complete this thread. Thank you again ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a new enough Intel CPU (IvyBridge or newer), you can use the RDRAND instruction.

This can be used via the [_rdrand16_step(), _rdrand32_step() and _rdrand64_step()](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_p32rdrand_u.htm) intrinsic functions.

Available via VS2012/13, Intel compiler and gcc.

The generated random number is originally seeded on a **real** random number. Designed for **NIST SP 800-90A** compliance, its randomness is very high.

Some numbers for reference:

On an IvyBridge dual core laptop with HT (2.3GHz), 2^32 (4 Gigs) random 32bit numbers took 5.7 seconds for single thread and 1.7 seconds with OpenMP.

Comment: How this answers the OP's question?

Comment: It's an alternative and fast solution for generating random numbers. This was the essence of the question - how to generate numbers fast. If the OP thinks it's irrelevant, I'll delete the answer

Comment: That's interesting egur.  I though this was only available with Broadwell but that's for RdSeed.  I don't really know the difference.

Comment: This explains it.  http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/11/17/the-difference-between-rdrand-and-rdseed  RDRAND is really cool. Thanks!

Comment: Both are security grade random number generators. The newer one RdSeed is slower and a better (security) usually acts as a good seed for external pseudo random number generator.

Comment: Wait, according to that link RDRAND is still a PRNG "In contrast, RDRAND is the output of a 128-bit PRNG"  and not a TRNG like RDSEED.

Comment: Correct, I should correct my answer. RdRand is seeded by an entropy source and it's very hard to re-seed it (no interface for that).

Comment: @egur Thank you for the tip, though it's not really what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, how come that paralleling the generation on two cores divided the computation time by more than two?

Comment: @Liam It's 2 core 4 threads (Hyperthreading). Not as fast as 4 cores, but much better than 2 cores. Aren't you looking for a fast random number generator?

Comment: @egur: Yes the final goal is to generator lots of random numbers as fast as possible, but I've been asked to look at the opportunities offered by computing on GPUs that's what motivated my question in the first place, I'll keep in mind what to proposed up there and will probably try to implement it to see if it fits well. Though I'm a bit embarrassed by not being able to reproduce my results the way I could do if I had to input a seed in the generator.

Comment: On my tests, `std::mt19937` is about 100 times faster than RDRAND on a tight loop.